# Android In-App billing only one time on PayPal SDK

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm building an android app, but I have a problem on PayPal SDK. Pratically, I want to pay the app only one time, like a managed item on official Google In-App Billing. So, if I change the device, I don't want pay again!

I'm reading the official docs, but I can't find something about this...
Actually, I'm following the "[Single payment](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md)" but is like a unmanaged item on official Google In-App Billing...

How can I manage this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely following the question.  Are you using the PayPal SDK for digital goods?  If so, this isn't allowed by the Google App-store, so the PayPal SDK doesn't really support that use case.

Comment: You can always do [future payments](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md), which will set up an agreement between the customer, your servers, and PayPal's servers.  This will remain even if the user switches devices.